# StyleCop plugin for overriding / implementing summary XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, stylecop, summary

I am exceptionally anal when it comes to StyleCop. I like to ensure that my class libraries are well laid out, maintainable, and appropriately documented.

Say for example I create an interface:

```
public interface ICustomImpl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Say hello!
    /// </summary>
    void SayHello();
}
```

and then I implement my interface

```
public class Hello : ICustomImpl
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        //impl
    }
}
```

StyleCop will now complain that I have not added a summary tag to my method implementation, however I have a summary tag on the interface.

Are there any known plugins that will automatically copy summary tags where available?

**Note:** I would like this to work for interface implementations and method overrides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). Well worth the price, it will do what you are looking for, plus write comments from scratch for many different methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tangent to your initial problem and GhostDoc is the correct answer.  This is just an alternative:

You could also be able to use the `<inheritdoc />` tag for any classes that have derived this interface.